# How do you confirm solutions to a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The question is as follows:

Consider the following partial differntial equation (PDE)

$2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} = u$

where $u=u(x,y)$ is the unknown function.

Define the following functions:

$u_1(x,y):=xy^2, u_2(x,y)=\sin(xy)$ and $u_3(x,y)=e^{\frac{1}{3}(x-y)}$

Which of these functions are solutions to the above PDE?

Any walkthroughs, description of methods, links to resources would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting these functions in the partial differential equation?

Comment: Have you computed the LHS for the given functions and looked at the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as you would an ordinary differential equation.

For each of $u_1,u_2,u_3$, do the following for this equation:

- Calculate the relevant partial derivatives: that is, find $(u_1)_{xx},(u_1)_{yy},(u_2)_{xx},(u_2)_{yy},(u_3)_{xx},(u_3)_{yy}$
- Substitute these values into the original PDE (which is $2u_{xx} + 2u_{yy} = u$): you're just picking $u = u_1$ when you use $u_1$ as the potential solution, and $u=u_2$ and $u=u_3$ in the other cases.
- Substitute in the corresponding function $u_1$ or $u_2$ or $u_3$ for $u$.

Remember that function equality necessitates equality for *all* inputs for the functions. Thus, you should either ...

- ...perform manipulations algebraically to try and arrive at a true statement. For example, if you did manipulations and concluded with $1=1$ or whatever, then the two functions are equal (translating to the function you used being a solution).
- ...see if there's an input for which the two sides are not equal. For example, if I had, more simply, wanted to check if $x^2 = x^9$, I could see that if I put in $x=1/2$ I get two very different values. Thus the functions are not equal (which would translate into $u_1$ or $u_2$ or $u_3$, whichever you used, not being a valid solution).

Comment: After doing the computation you mentioned, I arrived at this solution but I'm not sure about the part to check if these are valid solutions of the PDE. $u_1 = 2y^2 + 4x$, $u_2 = -4\sin{xy}$, $u_3 = 0$

Comment: To see if the solutions are valid, you just want to make sure the left side of the equation genuinely does equal the right side. Sometimes it might be obvious, like if you got $\tan(x) = \tan(x)$ or something - sometimes it's not-so-obvious if there is equality, and thus my statement on algebraic manipulations. It's easier to show inequality though - if the left-hand side and the right-hand side give you different results for the same input, they're unequal. Thus my example in the last bullet point in my post.

Comment: That said it would be difficult to address any potential errors or misunderstandings without concretely seeing what you've done thus far or where exactly you're stuck

Comment: This is what I have so far. $u_1=2y^2+4x$ ,$u_2=−4sin{xy}$, $u_3=0$

Comment: How did you get those values, exactly? $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are given in the problem, you don't need to be changing their definitions...

Comment: No, I mean by inputting it into the PDE and applying $2f_{xx} + 2f_{yy}$. I did this for all $u_1,u_2,u_3$. Then the output were the things I mentioned above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93141/discussion-between-jkong-and-eevee-trainer).

Answer (score 0):

- $2\cdot0+2\cdot2x=xy^2$ ?
- $2(-y^2\sin(xy))+2(-x^2\sin(xy))=\sin(xy)$ ?
- $2\dfrac{e^{(x-y)/3}}9+2\dfrac{e^{(x-y)/3}}9=e^{(x-y)/3}$ ?